# How do I create a method that meet this condition and return them?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

How do I make a method that has an array of size x, fill it with random numbers between y and z, then return the array? When I call the method I will have a certain size of the array(x) and then I will have the range of z and y.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Random.ints(streamSize, origin, bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) to create an `IntStream` of random values which are collected into array:

```java
public static int[] buildArray(int size, int from, int to) {
    return new Random() // or ThreadLocalRandom.current()
            .ints(size, from, to) // IntStream
            .toArray();
}
```